# Running mix task of sub app in umbrella projects root crashes

Tags: elixir

I made a simple task in the sub app(phoenix framework) of an umbrella project.

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Apidocs do
  defmodule Generate do
    use Mix.Task

    @shortdoc "Crawls products for a given store id, or all stores if no store id is given."

    def run([]) do
      Mix.Task.run "compile"
      Mix.Task.run "phoenix.swagger.generate", ["./web/static/assets/apidocs/snappy_api_v1.json"]
    end
  end
end
```

It runs well when I run it at `./apps/sub_app/`, but It crashes when I run it at root of the umbrella project (`./`)

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Example.Mixfile.application/0 is undefined or private
    Example.Mixfile.application()
    lib/mix/tasks/swagger.generate.ex:45: Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.Swagger.Generate.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:294: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:370: Code.require_file/2
```

I understand it can't find `application` at the umbrella project.
Is there anyway to run this task in right way?

Comment: What if you do `Mix.Task.run "phoenix.swagger.generate", ["./apps/sub_app/web/static/assets/apidocs/snappy_api_v1.json"]`? If this works, it's probably a path issue and the hardcoded path can be removed using `__DIR__`.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks. But the error occurs before that.

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem of phoenix_swagger.
I will close this question.